# How can I analyze C# intra-assembly dependencies?

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis, dependencies, mono

I'm working on a software project in C# whose source code is mostly is compiled to one assembly.  Let's call it `Monolith.dll`.  I have since decided that I should probably split `Monolith.dll` into smaller assemblies.  For reasons that are beyond the scope of this question, `Monolith.dll`'s intra-assembly dependencies are somewhat complicated.

Specifically, my needs are:

- I'm not interested in `Monolith.dll`'s dependencies on *other* assemblies, projects, or solutions.
- I want to know which classes in `Monolith.dll` use which *other* classes in `Monolith.dll`.
- This is my project, so I have complete control of the source code for `Monolith.dll`.
- I use Linux, so any recommendations must run on it.  It's okay if there's no GUI.
- The project is written entirely in C#; there is no unmanaged code.

**What tools are available that will let me do this, and how can I use them?**